# Determine if table can be truncated/deleted, run script, and loop back

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, if-statement, try-catch, truncate

I need to try to truncate tables and if they can GREAT do other stuff to the table but if they can't be truncated run through some script and then after that try truncate again and repeat.
Something like this *to start*

```
    SELECT TABLE_NAME
    INTO #tbls
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' 
    AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
    --No temps or views
    AND TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE 'tmp%'
    AND TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE 'temp%'
    AND TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE 'vw%'

SELECT @tbl_cnt = COUNT(*)  FROM #tbls 

WHILE @tbl_cnt > 0 -- for each  table
BEGIN
SET @tbl_nm  = (SELECT top 1 TABLE_NAME FROM #tbls) 

select  @sql = 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' + @tbl_nm 

BEGIN TRY
    EXEC(@sql) --truncate works 
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
--STUFF HERE TO DO WHEN TRUNCATE FAILS
END CATCH

/*LOOP BACK AND TRY TO TRUNCATE*/

/*more steps after successful truncate*/

@tbl_cnt = @tbl_cnt -1
DELETE FROM #tbls WHERE #tbls.TABLE_NAME = @tbl_nm
END
```

at the end it would be

```
WHILE @tbl_cnt > 0 
try to truncate
    if it works
    do more stuff
if it doesn't 
    do other stuff
try to truncate again
    Loop back to first truncate
```

try/catch might or might not be the way to go, tried other methods and that's the one I am working with now, just having a mental block with this. Any assistance appreciated.

Comment: The word "loop" implies that you'll keep trying until some condition is met.   Is that the case, and if so, what is the condition?

Comment: This has all the signs of being an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: The "do other stuff" part should take care of the loops so that the table will be truncated. I currently have this working without a way to loop back but I have to run the script manually 2-3 times to not get a truncate failed error. would like it so we can implement in production and only need to run it once. a with cte might work but that would mean it would loop through table that where already truncated. Just want it to retry truncate for tables that failed. I guess at the end would need to add a way to not end up with an infinite loop if a table is being overly stubborn.

Comment: not an xy as I stated "try/catch might or might not be the way to go, tried other methods and that's the one I am working with now". 
what's needed is clearly stated -
if can be truncated YAY continue with other stuff,
if not do something else,
try truncating again

Comment: Seems to me your code would already do what you're asking, except that it might run infinitely.   You just need to add an additional condition to the WHILE loop to stop looping when some condition is met.  You decide what condition.

Comment: Tip: You ought to add [`QuoteName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) around `@tbl_nm` when assembling the `truncate` statement. That will prevent problems caused by _funny_ table names. And prefix the table name with the schema name.